# Forever or domain - which of them is better for node.js continuous work

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I want my node app run continuously. I'm sure that some crashes can appear during the app's work. Nowadays i can see 3 ways of making an app work continuously:

1. Start my app with [forever](https://npmjs.org/package/forever), so when the app crashes forever will restart it automatically
2. Use [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) module to catch errors and start the app again when "error" event is emitted
3. *deprecated* process.on('uncaughtException')

The question is: which of these 3 ways is better to use. It seems to me like there's no exact answer to this question, so any comments are welcome.

In my opinion the first one is more appropriate because node process memory consumption doesn't grow with time - each time the node process crashes forever starts another one.

Comment: "Which is better" questions are bad - admitting that your question has no exact answer is worse.

Comment: I know this. Nevertheless i hope that i am not right and there's an exact answer to this question

Comment: depending on which system you are on [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) might also be an alternative

Comment: @zeMirco does it exist in lucid? Never heard of it before

Answer (score 10):

Ah, that's a tricky question. First of all, [`domains`](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) approach differs from [`forever`](https://npmjs.org/package/forever) in that it doesn't force you to restart the whole Node process. Say, for example, your Node application processes requests coming from several clients simultaneously. By carefully configuring your domains you (at least, in theory) will be able to prevent other requests from failing when one of the requests throws an error.

However, in practice to get domains work some components of your application has to be `domain`-aware. That applies to third-party components, too. For example, a database connection module that uses a pool of connections internally, should not wrap them into it's own domain, but rather check if the callback has a domain attached to it already. Otherwise, an exception thrown in a database code would be caught in a module's own domain and your domain wouldn't know about it. So, in order to use domains with third-party code you have to heck first if that code was written with `domains` in mind.

`forever` simply restarts your application whenever it crashes. It sounds like a worse idea than `domains`, but it also doesn't impose any specific requirements over a third-party code. Thus, you can use whatever library or module you want. You also don't have to put any complicated error recovery logic into your code. Sometimes having a simple codebase is more important than having non-failing yet complex one.

As for `process.on('uncaughtException')` I wouldn't use it. It's deprecated now, so it will probably be removed at some point.

---

### Here's my breakdown:

1. `forever`

   #### Pros:

   - lets you keep your codebase simpler and smaller
   - allows you to write your application logic first and think about error handling later

   #### Cons:

   - Single uncaught exception causes all other requests to fail

   #### Use when:

   - Your Node process and your requests are cheap
   - Clients can retry on error
2. `domains`

   #### Pros:

   - Broken request doesn't break other clients
   - Node process stays up longer reducing your overall downtime
   - [See also `domains+cluster` combo (Thanks, Isaac!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611749/forever-or-domain-which-of-them-is-better-for-node-js-continuous-work#comment20409657_14614261)

   #### Cons:

   - Can be used with domain-aware 3rd-party libraries
   - Requires additional logic in your program

   #### Use when:

   - Your requests or your Node process are expensive (e.g. file uploads, streaming data)
   - Single-node uptime is important
3. `process.on('uncaughtException')` don't use it.

---

### Notes

1. *[Isaac Z. Schlueter](https://npmjs.org/~isaacs) and [Felix Geisendörfer](https://npmjs.org/~felixge) talked about domains in [13th episode of NodeUp](http://nodeup.com/thirteen)*
2. *There's [a recent article explaining the difference between `forever` and Unix's `systemd`](http://savanne.be/articles/deploying-node-js-with-systemd/). You may find it useful.*

Comment: This is a good answer.  It's worth mentioning that domains+cluster is a powerful combination.  I use this when developing the npmjs.org site.  If there's an exception, the domain handler just closes the server.  The master process sees this, and then spins up another cluster worker.  This is wrapped up a bit in http://npm.im/cluster-master

Comment: @isaacs Oh, yeah, I looked into it after I've listened to your npm-www episode with Visnu. I've checked some modules you've mentioned and will probably try some of them.

Comment: seems like process.on('uncaughtException') is no longer deprecated?